# Ingresar información en Textbox con salto de linea

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2015, WPF, C#

Tengo un control TextBox en el cual tengo la necesidad de escribir información poniendo un salto de línea. Muestro el código que ocupo.

XAML

```
<TextBox Name="dtwTextOutput" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0"
TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="200" Height="230" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   IsReadOnly="True" 
TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Focusable="True"/>
```

C#

```
private void btnCargarMov_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listMov = SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal();
        var listDetMov = SdDetalleMovimiento.ListaDetalleMovimiento();

        foreach (var mov in listMov)
        {
            dtwTextOutput.Text = string.Empty;
            dtwTextOutput.Text = mov.Nombre + "\r\n";

            foreach (var det in listDetMov)
            {
                dtwTextOutput.Text = det.FotoGrama + "\r\n";
            }
        } 
    }
```

Con este código que ocupo solo me muestra una línea.

[image: TextBox WPF]

Comment: Debe de ser porque estás manejando un TextBox. TextBox  generalmente no maneja los saltos de línea. Intenta con un TextArea o algún equivalente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

un par de cosas..

Usa Enviroment.NewLine para agregar un salto de linea.

```
dtwTextOutput.Text = string.Empty;
dtwTextOutput.Text = mov.Nombre + "\r\n";
foreach (var det in listDetMov)
{
    dtwTextOutput.Text = det.FotoGrama + "\r\n";
}
```

En tu codigo, siempre se va a ver solo la ultima linea, ya que estas borrando el contenido cada vez que le agregas un texto al objeto!

deberia ser:

```
dtwTextOutput.Text = dtwTextOutput.Text  + string.Empty;
dtwTextOutput.Text = dtwTextOutput.Text + mov.Nombre + Enviroment.NewLine;
foreach (var det in listDetMov)
{
    dtwTextOutput.Text = dtwTextOutput.Text  + det.FotoGrama + Enviroment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Gracias si funciono, te cuento que mantuve el "\r\n"